# jquery mobile form submit not working when hash # in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile 1.0 alpha 4.1 to build a login form.

The login form submits just fine the first time when I load it from:
http://m.myapp.local/

the form action is the following:

```
<form action="http://m.myapp.local/default/login" method="post">
```

this works fine the first login attempt, but when the login fails, we return to the following URL (this is jquery mobile doing this):
http://m.myapp.local/#default/login

Now when I try to login again / submit the form again nothing happens and I can debug to find the error. It says:

```
Javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined
```

When I debug even further, I see that jquery mobile is trying to submit to the following url:
http://m.myapp.local/default/logindefault/login
instead of
http://m.myapp.local/default/login

of course, that url does not exist which causes the error. Question is, how can I prevent jq mobile from behaving this way?

Full form:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
<form action="http://m.myapp.local/default/login" method="post">            
    
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="center">
<input placeholder="Shop Name" id="login_sitename" type="text" value="" name="sitename" />
<input placeholder="Email" id="login_username" type="text" value="" name="username" />                      
<input placeholder="Password" id="login_password" type="password" name="password" />
</div>
                            
<button type="submit" data-theme="b">Log in</button>
</form>
</div>
```

a strange thing I've noticed is that when I remove the hash tag from the url and submit the form again, it all works, so it definitely has something to do with that.

BUT, when I remove the hash tag, it also stops using transitions, the back button is gone as well and the jquery mobile "loading" dialog is also gone...

---

seems like it's a jquery bug. When using alpha 2, it works...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you post a little more code so we can take a look at what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is this single/multi page, ajax/changePage()/normal form submission, how do you transition from page to page, etc...

Comment: This might help: http://codeasp.net/blogs/teisenhauer/microsoft-net/1049/jquery-mobile-login-dialog-box or this: http://devgrow.com/jquery-mobile-php-mvc-framework/

Comment: Hi Phill, I have updated my code above with the full form code. I have used the standard way of submitting forms in jquery mobile, so I guess it's normal form submissions? Or is it ajax/changepage?

Comment: the codeasp.net example seems to use another kind of hash in the url's, maybe that has something to do with it? /#./user/login

Comment: @Phil, seems like it's a jquery but: when I use the older alpha as you showed me in your example, things work just fine: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

Comment: I would look over the new documentation on form submission as it has changed: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/../../docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html I think you need to add the rel=external attribute to your form (guessing) but read the docs and it should help

Comment: thanks, but adding rel=external would removes all AJAX/jquery mobile back button behaviour, I'll look into the docs for a possible solution...

Answer (score 1):

You might try diabling AJAX for form posting. I had the same issues on my site:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-sample.html

You can try this in the submission link:
data-ajax="false"

Answer (score 1):

Try using a "%23" (without the quotes) in place of the # symbol. So if the URL reads

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-sample.html

replace it as

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/%23docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Hope this helps!